# UITableView, make footer not bounce when table view scrolled till the end

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll, footer

When I scroll to the bottom of my table view, the last element (intended to be a footer) bounces with the tableview object.

Is there a way I can make this last item / footer item, pin to the bottom of the screen when it is reached?

Comment: can't you turn off bouncing all together? e.g. .bounces=NO; .alwaysBounceVertical=NO;

Comment: @almas that worked, but I like the bounce, I just don't want the footer to bounce

Answer (score 0):

```
    You can use below Method, in this way, when you go down in UITableView , 
at that time Stop or turn off bouncing all together? 
e.g. .bounces=NO; .alwaysBounceVertical=NO
    otherwise Set Yes To all.

    this way may be helpful to you.

      - (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
        {
            NSLog(@"scrollView.contentOffset.y-%f",scrollView.contentOffset.y);

            NSLog(@"tblView.contentSize.height=%f",tblView.contentSize.height-tblView.frame.size.height);

            if ([scrollView isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]])
            {
                if(scrollView.contentOffset.y == tblView.contentSize.height-tblView.frame.size.height)
                {
                    // we are at the end
                    //Sp do wahtever want to do here.
                    //set bounce no
                }
                else
                {
                   //not at END.
                   //set bounce Yes
                }
            }
        }
```